# AIR（ActionScript） for iOS FacebookMobile.login() use browser?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, facebook-actionscript-api

I want to use facebook graph api from air for ios app.
When FacebookMobile.login(), i use stagewebview. is successed.

but, i want to login that use safari.
FacebookMobille.login() webView:StageWebView is optional.
it means that i can login with safari ? or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a Native Extension instead of using JS.

http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/#iosgv

A tutorial here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/goviral-ane-ios.html

Comment: thank you answer! i try to read the tutorial. but i don't think only use ANE, because i could it with twitter. open auth url on safari and callback url scheme. so i think,  with facebook, if i can use 'getloginurl()' , open the url on safari, and callback url scheme. but TwitterMobile.getLoginURL() is not.